# Which string hashing algorithm produces 32-bit or 64-bit signed integers?

Tags: python, postgresql, hash, hashlib, signed-integer

I want to hash strings of variable length (6-60 characters long) to 32-bit [signed integers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html) in order to save disk space in PostgreSQL.

I don't want to encrypt any data, and the hashing function needs to be reproducible and callable from Python. The problem is that I can only find Algorithms that produce **unsigned integers** (like CityHash), which therefore produce values of up to 2^32 instead of 2^31.

This is what I have thus far:

```
import math
from cityhash import CityHash32

string_ = "ALPDAKQKWTGDR"
hashed_string = CityHash32(string_)
print(hashed_string, len(str(hashed_string)))
max_ = int(math.pow(2, 31) - 1)
print(hashed_string > max_)
```

Comment: Just interpret the unsigned integer as a signed integer?

Comment: @Ryan The result has to be between -2147483648 and +2147483647. How will your suggestion help? Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Subtract 2147483648.

Comment: @Ryan Looks like a simple solution. I guess it would lead to the same amount of collisions as the original value and less than truncating a longer hash?

Comment: Well, it gets you 32 bits. There are other points to consider, though. What do you do with the strings that lets you throw them away and only store their hashes?

Comment: @Ryan You solved it. Thank you!! But didn't post it as an answer. I could close the question if you did. The idea is to save disk space by storing integers and not strings, and hash strings I want to query on the fly.

Comment: Though I realised 32 bit will not be sufficient, 64 should be.

Comment: Erm, how are you handling collisions, then? If that was the reason for changing to 64-bit, you will probably want to both (a) use a cryptographic hash and (b) read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150107/discussion-between-tryptofame-and-ryan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan answered the question in the comments. Simply subtract 2147483648 (= 2^31) from the hash result.

```
CityHash32(string_) - math.pow(2, 31)
```

or

```
CityHash64(string_) - math.pow(2, 63)
```

Ryan also mentioned that using SHA-512 and truncating the result to the desired number of digits will lead to less collisions than the method above.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function int_hash(s text)
returns int as $$

    select ('x' || left(md5(s), 8))::bit(32)::int
    ;
$$ language sql immutable;

select int_hash('1');
  int_hash  
------------
 -993377736
```

Comment: @Scoots The way it is broken has nothing to do with the question other than that with 4 bytes only the collision rate will be high.

Answer (score 0):

I typically wouldn't use a 32-bit hash except for very low cardinality because it of course risks collisions a lot more than a 64-bit hash would. Databases readily support bigint 8-byte (64-bit) integers. Consider [this table](https://preshing.com/images/small-probabilities.png) for some hash collision probabilities.

If you're using Python ≥3.6, you absolutely don't need to use a third-party package for this, and you don't need to subtract an offset either, since you can **directly generate a signed 64-bit or [variable bit-length hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#shake-variable-length-digests) utilizing `shake_128`**:

```
import hashlib
from typing import Dict, List


class Int8Hash:

    BYTES = 8
    BITS = BYTES * 8
    BITS_MINUS1 = BITS - 1
    MIN = -(2**BITS_MINUS1)
    MAX = 2**BITS_MINUS1 - 1

    @classmethod
    def as_dict(cls, texts: List[str]) -> Dict[int, str]:
        return {cls.as_int(text): text for text in texts}  # Intentionally reversed.

    @classmethod
    def as_int(cls, text: str) -> int:
        seed = text.encode()
        hash_digest = hashlib.shake_128(seed).digest(cls.BYTES)
        hash_int = int.from_bytes(hash_digest, byteorder='big', signed=True)
        assert cls.MIN <= hash_int <= cls.MAX
        return hash_int

    @classmethod
    def as_list(cls, texts: List[str]) -> List[int]:
        return [cls.as_int(text) for text in texts]
```

Usage:

```
>>> Int8Hash.as_int('abc')
6377388639837011804
>>> Int8Hash.as_int('xyz')
-1670574255735062145

>>> Int8Hash.as_list(['p', 'q'])
[-539261407052670282, -8666947431442270955]
>>> Int8Hash.as_dict(['i', 'j'])
{8695440610821005873: 'i', 6981288559557589494: 'j'}
```

To generate a 32-bit hash instead, set `Int8Hash.BYTES` to 4.

Disclaimer: I have not written a statistical unit test to verify that this implementation returns uniformly distributed integers.